# Using trait in namespace

Tags: php, traits

I'm trying to use a trait in namespace.

```
namespace {

class Glob {

   function __toString() {
      return 'Global Namespace<br />';
   }
}

$Ng = new \special\Glob();

echo $Ng;

}

namespace special {

trait myTrait {
    public $config = 'This is Config Trait';
}

class Glob {
    use \special\myTrait;
    public $v = [];
    function __toString() {
        return 'Special Namespace<br />';
    }
    function __set( $index,$value ){
        $this->v[$index] = $value;
    }
    function __get( $index ){
        $this->v[$index];
    }
}
}
```

Note that this is just a test so auto loading here doesn't mean much.

it throws a Fatal error :

```
 Fatal error: Class 'special\Glob' not found in C:\wamp\www\Learnings\namespace.php on line 23
```

But in a global namespace it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap your namespace blocks around, like:

```
namespace special {

    trait myTrait {
        public $config = 'This is Config Trait';
    }

    class Glob {
        use \special\myTrait;
        public $v = [];
        function __toString() {
            return 'Special Namespace<br />';
        }
        function __set( $index,$value ){
            $this->v[$index] = $value;
        }
        function __get( $index ){
            $this->v[$index];
        }
    }
}

namespace {

    class Glob {

        function __toString() {
            return 'Global Namespace<br />';
        }
    }

    $Ng = new \special\Glob();

    echo $Ng;

}
```

Comment: Many Thanks. That was the answer I've been looking for Does it really matter to have the global namespace at the end of other namespaces ?